# WF4 re-hosted in WPF : Loading saved workflows does not work with the published application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

I downloaded [this  Workfloff project](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Workflow-9e867448) by Ron Jacobs. It is a simple solution with three (Activity, ActivityDesigner and a WPF Rehosted) projects.

[image: Project image]

In debug mode, everything runs perfectly. But after I publish the project with ClickOnce, I can not load any saved XAML workflow files with the published application!? The message "**Could not generate view**" appears in the designer and I get the error message "**The component** 'MyActivityLibrary.Designer' **does not have a resource identified by the URI** '/MyActivityLibrary.Design;component/myactivitydesigner.xaml'". But actually the URI is in theere `<sap:ActivityDesigner x:Class="MyActivityLibrary.Design.MyActivityDesigner"`. I must mention that this error only occurs with workflows which has their own custom designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution Ive found was to merge both Activity libraries into one library class. Now I have one Activity library with all the activities together with the  designers. And one WPF application library.